# Do the tangent points of the circles that are tangent to the sides of a triangle lie on a conic section?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

I came up with this feature about 3 months ago while using GeoGebra

If we have a triangle, and we draw the three circles that touch its sides from the outside, then the six points of contact lie on one conic section.
[image]
Is this property already known?
How do we prove it anyway?

Comment: I feel that the property is somewhat similar to Conway's circle

Comment: Are you familiar with Carnot's theorem on conics? It gives you a relationship for 6 points on a triangle to form a conic. You then just have to length-cause, which should be obvious for an excircle.

Comment: Thank you @CalvinLin Indeed, the result becomes self-evident when the Karno theorem is applied, as all lengths are equal and equal to the half-circumference of the triangle.

Comment: Can you self answer this then?

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the following diagram:
[image]
We know that the tangents to a circle drawn from a point outside it are of equal length, therefore:
$AQ=AT$

$⇒AB+BQ=AC+CT\cdots [1]$

$BQ=BD\cdots [2]$

$CT=CD\cdots [3]$

$[1],[2],[3]⇒AB+BD=AC+CD=\frac{AB+BC+CA}{2}=S$

$⇒AQ=AT=S$

In the same way we can find:

$AQ=AT=BN=BV=CM=CP=S$

$AN=BQ,CV=BP,AM=CT$

Now we can apply [Carnot's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem_(conics)):

$\frac{AQ}{BQ}\cdot\frac{AN}{BN}\cdot\frac{BV}{CV}\cdot\frac{BP}{CP}\cdot\frac{CM}{AM}\cdot\frac{CT}{AT}=1$

Hence the points $M,N,P,Q,T,V$ lie on a conic section

Comment: I was busy this morning, now that I wrote the proof @CalvinLin

Answer (score 0):

Now when I looked at the Carnot's Theorem page on the Cutting the Knot website and looked at the related topics, I found that my theorem had already been discovered.

https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/InExConics.shtml

Comment: Here is a, in-depth [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.15232.pdf) focusing on triads of conics, but establishing at first the theorem about the so called "Yu's conic" (that I didn't know).

Comment: Thank you, @Jean-Marie, the research paper is very nice. I already know some of the properties mentioned here, but most of the properties I did not know previously.